# No longer receiving emails from contact form?

Tags: php, forms, email, phpmailer

I have set up a contact on my site and everything was working just fine. I was filling in all the information and upon submitting the form I was getting the confirmation message and then the email sent to both my personal account and also website account.

I sent myself a few emails over the past couple of weeks in order to ensure everything was working well and had no problem until today. Now for some reason when am email is sent it does not go to either of my recipient addresses (personal or website)!

The code has not changed at all the only thing that has changed is the fact that I am not getting the emails any more? PHP mailer is being used and I am a total novice at PHP (form was pre built). I have tried sending from local host as well as my website host and also tried from different computers. Nothing seems to work at all!

I even uploaded the original form from the zip file in case I had changed the code, updated the details (email addresses) and tested that but still no email?

What could have gone wrong? I have no idea what could have happened but if anyone does have an idea of where I should start to look it would be great help.

So I have just found an error message that was emailed to my webhost mail:

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
```

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

```
  darren_morton@hotmail.com
    SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL
FROM:<000test@zeus2.easy-internet.co.uk> SIZE=6920:
    host mxserv1.easy-internet.co.uk [81.27.85.244]:
    550-Verification failed for <000test@zeus2.easy-internet.co.uk>
    550-Previous (cached) callout verification failure
    550 Invalid sender <000test@zeus2.easy-internet.co.uk>

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

Return-path: <000test@zeus2.easy-internet.co.uk>
Received: from 000test by zeus2.easy-internet.co.uk with local (Exim 4.82)
        (envelope-from <000test@zeus2.easy-internet.co.uk>)
        id 000000-000000-00
        for myemailaddress@gmail.com; Sat, 21 Jun 2014 01:06:53 +0100
To: myemailaddress@gmail.com
Subject: Message from Test
X-PHP-Script: myemailaddress@gmail.com/sandbox/quform/process.php for 88.888.888.888
Date: Sat, 21 Jun 2014 01:06:53 +0100
From: DMP <myemailaddress@gmail.com>
Reply-To: this@yahoo.com
Message-ID: <00000000000000000000000000@www.mywebsite.co.uk>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.4 (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
        boundary="b1_c68a1525831aedf1c0370e9041e52c7a"

--b1_c68a1525831aedf1c0370e9041e52c7a
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

To view this email please use HTML compatible email software.


--b1_c68a1525831aedf1c0370e9041e52c7a
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<html>
```

I have removed the code from here as it's just the body html etc.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Php version has been updated on server, and script use old php mailer version? I guess that no error messages are showed?

Comment: no error messages at all no.

Comment: Hm... it seems you will have to post code (html and php), and link to php mailer version you use.

Comment: In the above code the areas that are not commented out is where I put the details of where I want the emails to go. With them this way around I am getting an email delivered to my host email but not my yahoo. If I change them around the other way I get nothing? could this be an indication as to what is going wrong here?

Comment: @Margate - if the code you've got works when you send to one email address, but fails when you send it to Yahoo, the problem isn't with the code; that's working fine, otherwise you'd never get any email. So I'm assuming that the problem is that your emails are hitting Yahoo's spam filters, and getting blocked there. There are a few things you can do to try and avoid that - there are many questions on SO about this - but you'll need to do things like setting up SPF records to make your emails look less spammy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bouncing from your ISP's mail server when you send. It's not bouncing from hotmail or anywhere further upstream. It looks like your outbound authentication is failing - maybe you need to use the SMTP submission protocol rather than using defaults. Try these settings:

```
$mail->Host = 'mxserv1.easy-internet.co.uk';
$mail->Username = '000darr@zeus2.easy-internet.co.uk';
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
```

You're also using an old and buggy version of PHPailer - get the latest from [github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Hi Synchro, your totally correct. After changing the SMTP settings everything worked like a charm! I spent 8 hours trying to sort this out! What a headache. I did not set the SMTP from the start! Hopefully this will also help someone who is having the same issues in the future and save them the 8 hours I lost lol! Thank you very much for your kind help :  )